# sed command garbled for solaris

Tags: sed, solaris

I want to execute the below line:

```
sed -n '/description/!{H;d}; /description/ {x; /XCJDAST/p}; $ {x; /XCJDAST/p}' tsgroupsPrevious.xml
```

This is working fine for Unix but not working for solaris,giving command garbled error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -n '#Solaris version
/description/!{
   H;d
   }
/description/ {
   x; /XCJDAST/p
   }
$ {
  x; /XCJDAST/p
  }' tsgroupsPrevious.xml
```

- after a `d`, sed stop the script even with a `;` after, not in linux
- `;` is a substitute for line separator, not always available in non GNU sed script especially in group of action (and after command like `d`)
- also, comment must start on first character of a line